# Write a string within a list to one cell in a CSV file. Python 2.7 Windows 7

Tags: file, csv, output, cell

Is it possible to write a string stored into a list into a .CSV file into one cell?

I have a folder with files and I want to write the file names onto a .csv file.

Folder with files:

```
    Data.txt
    Data2.txt
    Data3.txt
```

Here is my code:

```
    import csv
    import os
    index = -1 
    filename = []
    filelist = []
    filelist = os.listdir("dirname")

        f = csv.writer(open("output.csv", "ab"), delimiter=",", quotechar=" ", quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

    for file in filelist:
        if (len(filelist) + index) <0: 
            break
        filename = filelist[len(filelist)+index]
        index -= 1
        f.writerow(filename)
```

Output I'm getting is one letter per cell in the .csv file:

```
      A B C D E F G H I       
    1 D a t a . t x t
    2 D a t a 2 . t x t
    3 D a t a 3 . t x t
```

Desired output would be to have it all in 1 cell. There should be three rows on the csv file with strings "Data.txt" in cell A1, "Data2.txt" in cell B1, and "Data3.txt" in cell C1:

```
      A          B
    1 Data.txt
    2 Data2.txt
    3 Data3.txt
```

Is it possible to do this? Let me know if you need more information. I am currently using Python 2.7 on Windows 7.

Solution/Corrected Code:

```
    import csv
    import os
    index = -1 
    filename = []
    filelist = []
    filelist = os.listdir("dirname")

        f = csv.writer(open("output.csv", "ab"), delimiter=",", quotechar=" ", quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

    for file in filelist:
        if (len(filelist) + index) <0: 
            break
        filename = filelist[len(filelist)+index]
        index -= 1
        f.writerow([filename]) #Need to send in a list of strings without the ',' as a delimiter since writerow expects a tuple/list of strings.
```

Comment: Please can you post the code that causes the issue, the code posted has some basic syntax errors and a missing import. Also you set index to `-1` and break if index is less than `0` causing the script not do anything.

Comment: Updated @Noelkd Sorry about that.

Comment: It's still not right, getting a syntax error on the if line because of a missing colon, can you take a look [at this](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Now it is :D Forgot to put that in when i rewrote it

Comment: output.csv should be a string

Comment: @Noelkd thanks for the website. I'll take account of that for future posts.

Comment: Can you post an example of the csv you want out, i.e. `file1.txt,file2.txt,file3.txt,output.csv,test.py`

Comment: That's all I want: Data.txt, Data2.txt, Data3.txt to be written to a single cell in the output.csv file. There should be three rows on the csv file with "Data.txt" in cell A1, "Data2.txt" in cell B1, and "Data3.txt" in cell C1. I changed "wb" to "ab" to append the files onto the .csv file @Noelkd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
import csv
import os

filelist = os.listdir("dirname")  # Use a real directory
f = csv.writer(open("output.csv", 'ab'), delimiter=",", quotechar=" ", quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
for file_name in filelist:
    f.writerow([file_name])
```

Writerow expects a sequence, for example  a list of strings. You're giving it a single string which it is then iterating over causing you to see each letter of the string with a `,` between.

Comment: That solved it. Never knew it was just to have the brackets :D That makes a lot of sense now. Have a great day! Thanks for all of the advice and help @Noelkd

Comment: No problem try to fix your code blocks in the question you only need a four space indent.

Answer (score 0):

you can also put each sentence/value that you want to be in 1 cell inside a list and all the internal lists inside one external list.

something like this:

```
import csv
import os

list_ = [["value1"], ["value2"], ["value3"]]
with open('test.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(list_)
```